# Why do I get an error for this delegate code?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I'm about to program a small app that has several gamemodes. Now I want the modes of the main class (in which the gamemode is set with a slider) to be displayed in a different class as a label. I get the error: Thread 1: Fatal Error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional Value.

I have a few ViewControllers. On the first I have the slider. On the second one I have two buttons to decide between truth or dare. And on the third one I have the label that should be changed. On the first ViewController there is the button "Start", which will start the Game.

I already tried to put the delegate in the viewDidLoad function but it didn't worked.

My Slider is in the class "ViewController", which is the main class. chooseButtonTapped is in the class "ThisViewController". The gamemode should be displayed in "ThisViewController" and is set with the slider in the class "ViewController".

Here are a few parts of my code:

My delegate:

```
protocol SpielmodusDelegate {
  func didChooseGamemode(gm: String)
}
```

My slider:

```
var selectionDelegate: SpielmodusDelegate!

@IBAction gamemodeSliderChanges(_ sender: UISlider) {
  if (currentValue > 0.8 && currentvalue < 1) {
    gamemodeLabel.text = dataSource[4]
    selectionDelegate.didChooseGamemode(gm: "Extrem") <-------ERROR
  }
}
```

My other class where you want to import the game mode:

```
@IBAction func chooseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"ViewController") as! ViewController
  selectionVC.selectionDelegate = self
  present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The extension on the class in which the game mode is to be imported:

```
extension ThisViewController: SpielmodusDelegate {
  func didChooseGamemode(gm: String) {
label.text = gm
  }
}
```

I have seen a few tutorials and read a few things about delegates but I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Whoever is implementing `didChooseGamemode` should send itself to the slider as its delegate. do you do that?

Comment: The code of the slider is mentioned above. I'm pretty new to Swift so I don't know how you mean it. Please don't take it as offense!

Comment: We need class names. What class is the "My slider" code in? What class is the `chooseButtonTapped` code in?

Comment: Also note that delegates should always be weak optionals. `weak var selectionDelegate: SpielmodusDelegate?`. This prevents reference cycles. As a side effect, this will fix your crash but it will cause a new issue so you still have the same underlying problem to resolve.

Comment: My Slider is in the class "ViewController", which is the main class. chooseButtonTapped is in the class "ThisViewController". The gamemode should be displayed in "ThisViewController" and is set with the slider in the class "ViewController".

Comment: Please put that information in your question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

After comments and additional information from the OP...

You are trying to use delegate / protocol in completely the wrong way.

What you want to do is set variables in your "next" view controllers.

Take a look at this:

[image]

Embed the First `ViewController` in a `UINavigationController`.

The First `ViewController` manages the slider.

When you tap the "Start" button, it will instantiate `SecondViewController` and sets ***its*** `currentMode` variable, and then push it onto the navigation stack.

When you tap either the "Truth" or "Dare" buttons, it will instantiate `ThirdViewController` and sets ***its*** `currentMode` and `buttonSelected` variables, and then push it onto the navigation stack.

Here is sample code:

```
import UIKit

enum GameModeValues: Int {
    case Easy
    case Normal
    case Difficult
    case Extrem
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var theSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var gamemodeLabel: UILabel!

    var currentMode: GameModeValues = .Easy

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theSlider.minimumValue = 0
        theSlider.maximumValue = 3.99

        theSlider.value = Float(currentMode.rawValue)

        gamemodeLabel.text = "\(currentMode)"

    }

    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let intValue = Int(sender.value)
        if currentMode.rawValue != intValue {
            currentMode = GameModeValues(rawValue: intValue) ?? GameModeValues.Easy
            gamemodeLabel.text = "\(currentMode)"
        }
    }

    @IBAction func startButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController {
            vc.currentMode = currentMode
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentMode: GameModeValues = .Easy

    @IBOutlet var gamemodeLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gamemodeLabel.text = "\(currentMode)"
    }

    @IBAction func truthButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        gotoThirdViewController("Truth")
    }

    @IBAction func dareButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        gotoThirdViewController("Dare")
    }

    func gotoThirdViewController(_ truthOrDare: String) -> Void {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ThirdViewController") as? ThirdViewController {
            vc.currentMode = currentMode
            vc.buttonSelected = truthOrDare
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentMode: GameModeValues = .Easy
    var buttonSelected: String = "Truth"

    @IBOutlet var gamemodeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var buttonSelectedLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        gamemodeLabel.text = "\(currentMode)"
        buttonSelectedLabel.text = buttonSelected
    }

}
```

and here is the Storyboard source so you can jump right in and see it in action:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14460.31" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="EzF-nU-R7k">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14460.20"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="wYk-Om-cIK">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="kaD-ge-RGe" customClass="ViewController" customModule="LaunchTest2" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="EDR-jw-bbQ">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cEy-pg-8yn">
                                <rect key="frame" x="170.5" y="205" width="34" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Start"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="startButtonTapped:" destination="kaD-ge-RGe" eventType="touchUpInside" id="9pa-6m-mdo"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <slider opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" value="0.5" minValue="0.0" maxValue="1" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="0UU-3B-stg">
                                <rect key="frame" x="18" y="295" width="339" height="31"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="sliderChanged:" destination="kaD-ge-RGe" eventType="valueChanged" id="rCT-Cq-cKf"/>
                                </connections>
                            </slider>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="RIp-YU-EZ0">
                                <rect key="frame" x="166.5" y="385" width="42" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="View Controller" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kNM-Z6-BFV">
                                <rect key="frame" x="129" y="124" width="117" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="0UU-3B-stg" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="V6S-9h-7yR" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="1Bg-Og-bpG"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="RIp-YU-EZ0" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="EDR-jw-bbQ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="GgG-qI-Zhp"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="0UU-3B-stg" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="cEy-pg-8yn" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="MMd-ja-8TW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="cEy-pg-8yn" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="kNM-Z6-BFV" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="Rbo-U2-VHe"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kNM-Z6-BFV" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="V6S-9h-7yR" secondAttribute="top" constant="60" id="ZDi-Ou-t1c"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="V6S-9h-7yR" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="0UU-3B-stg" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="n7E-Ik-Znh"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="RIp-YU-EZ0" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="0UU-3B-stg" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="pcX-zl-Mf3"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="cEy-pg-8yn" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="EDR-jw-bbQ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="sXu-6I-GZf"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kNM-Z6-BFV" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="EDR-jw-bbQ" secondAttribute="centerX" id="zKl-Us-iJy"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="V6S-9h-7yR"/>
                    </view>
                    <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="qyP-ln-h7M"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="gamemodeLabel" destination="RIp-YU-EZ0" id="zf6-DU-NeT"/>
                        <outlet property="theSlider" destination="0UU-3B-stg" id="7Ie-7w-jFw"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="geN-ym-2yS" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1068" y="215.44227886056973"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Second View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="sf5-TB-sau">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="SecondViewController" id="h9x-Im-nTy" customClass="SecondViewController" customModule="LaunchTest2" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="RXf-JA-XkI">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yLo-sI-rY9">
                                <rect key="frame" x="169" y="242" width="37" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Truth"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="truthButtonTapped:" destination="h9x-Im-nTy" eventType="touchUpInside" id="5xP-1e-c08"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" buttonType="roundedRect" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8BM-bn-86x">
                                <rect key="frame" x="171" y="332" width="33" height="30"/>
                                <state key="normal" title="Dare"/>
                                <connections>
                                    <action selector="dareButtonTapped:" destination="h9x-Im-nTy" eventType="touchUpInside" id="njl-le-CMY"/>
                                </connections>
                            </button>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Second View Controller" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="3Od-JO-yEA">
                                <rect key="frame" x="97.5" y="80" width="180" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Game Mode Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Uct-vv-SSq">
                                <rect key="frame" x="118" y="161" width="139" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="8BM-bn-86x" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="RXf-JA-XkI" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Hrm-TE-ocS"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Uct-vv-SSq" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="3Od-JO-yEA" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="cky-Ow-tOC"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="8BM-bn-86x" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="yLo-sI-rY9" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="d8A-4y-Tt7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="yLo-sI-rY9" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Uct-vv-SSq" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="f3t-gw-hg7"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3Od-JO-yEA" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="LzW-mg-KAw" secondAttribute="top" constant="60" id="iKq-Nc-Wpn"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Uct-vv-SSq" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="RXf-JA-XkI" secondAttribute="centerX" id="oAh-7Z-5Uc"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="3Od-JO-yEA" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="RXf-JA-XkI" secondAttribute="centerX" id="rcc-r2-6jz"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="yLo-sI-rY9" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="RXf-JA-XkI" secondAttribute="centerX" id="ubo-Xt-2bT"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="LzW-mg-KAw"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="gamemodeLabel" destination="Uct-vv-SSq" id="gez-Ie-G4n"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="IIe-79-ZbY" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="1746" y="215"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Navigation Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="Gj0-Xb-uvT">
            <objects>
                <navigationController automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets="NO" id="EzF-nU-R7k" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <toolbarItems/>
                    <navigationBar key="navigationBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="c80-8v-3ra">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="20" width="375" height="44"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                    </navigationBar>
                    <nil name="viewControllers"/>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="kaD-ge-RGe" kind="relationship" relationship="rootViewController" id="LEe-hD-Fyl"/>
                    </connections>
                </navigationController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="5UX-yJ-buo" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="370" y="215"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Third View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="XIm-bw-14T">
            <objects>
                <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ThirdViewController" id="Sg0-vM-Ir7" customClass="ThirdViewController" customModule="LaunchTest2" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="eVd-jb-0fY">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Third View Controller" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="txR-9a-ybO">
                                <rect key="frame" x="107" y="80" width="161" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Game Mode Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2M0-8h-jtQ">
                                <rect key="frame" x="118" y="161" width="139" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Button Selected Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Zug-Dn-13z">
                                <rect key="frame" x="103" y="242" width="169" height="21"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="2M0-8h-jtQ" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="eVd-jb-0fY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="Eoi-YU-vc6"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Zug-Dn-13z" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="2M0-8h-jtQ" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="EtH-T4-MD5"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="txR-9a-ybO" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="BOa-UN-1aS" secondAttribute="top" constant="60" id="nyi-KX-pGE"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="txR-9a-ybO" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="eVd-jb-0fY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="qOD-65-vLb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="Zug-Dn-13z" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="eVd-jb-0fY" secondAttribute="centerX" id="rZa-Xu-pzH"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="2M0-8h-jtQ" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="txR-9a-ybO" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="wrI-a0-ak4"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="BOa-UN-1aS"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="buttonSelectedLabel" destination="Zug-Dn-13z" id="GLO-r2-gY6"/>
                        <outlet property="gamemodeLabel" destination="2M0-8h-jtQ" id="Ay0-dI-rmU"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="TPA-ns-oaF" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="2447" y="215"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

---

***(This was the initial answer, prior to comments and additional info)***

It sounds / looks like you have something else going wrong, which we don't see in your post. So... start with the basics, to make sure your protocol / delegate is setup correctly.

[image]

The Initial view controller is of class `ThisViewController`. It has a button connected to the `@IBAction func chooseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton)`.

The other view controller is of class `ViewController`. It has a `UISlider` connected to the `@IBAction func gamemodeSliderChanges(_ sender: UISlider)` (make sure it has a Storyboard ID of **ViewController**).

Use this code:

```
import UIKit

protocol SpielmodusDelegate: class {
    func didChooseGamemode(gm: String)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // use weak var for the delegate
    weak var selectionDelegate: SpielmodusDelegate?

    @IBAction func gamemodeSliderChanges(_ sender: UISlider) {
        if sender.value > 0.8 {
            selectionDelegate?.didChooseGamemode(gm: "Extrem")
        } else {
            selectionDelegate?.didChooseGamemode(gm: "Normal")
        }
    }

}

class ThisViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func chooseButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? ViewController {
            vc.selectionDelegate = self
            present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

}

extension ThisViewController: SpielmodusDelegate {
    func didChooseGamemode(gm: String) {
        print("Received: " + gm)
    }
}
```

and run the app.

Tapping the Button should present `ViewController` with the slider. As you drag the slider, you should see repeated prints in the Debug Console:

```
Received: Normal
Received: Normal
Received: Normal
Received: Normal
Received: Normal
Received: Extrem
Received: Extrem
Received: Extrem
etc...
```

That should work. If it does, compare that to how you have your current project set up.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think today is not my day.. I forgot the : class behind the protocol.

Comment: Now I don't have any error, but I'm still not getting any output. I have anything as you wrote. The only thing I've changed is that the vc.selectionDelegate = self is in the viewDidLoad(). Thats because the button is on the same ViewController as the slider. It's a start button.

Comment: *"the button is on the same ViewController as the slider"* -- that doesn't make any sense... The code you showed has a button in one view controller which, when tapped, ***presents*** a view controller that has a slider. If that's not what you're doing, you need to edit your question to explain what you *are* doing.

Comment: Could the problem be that the view of the label is not loaded? On the first viewContoller there is the slider. Then there is a second one. And on the third one is the label which should be changed. Is this the problem? Sorry for my bad English by the way.

Comment: It sounds like you are using protocol / delegate pattern completely wrong. In general, you use a delegate so a presented or child class can "communicate back to" it's presenter / parent. As I said, edit your question to better show/explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I will do, but what could you recommend me to use in this case?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and especially for your time!